# C# Cannot pass propertyInfo.propertyType in diamond syntax

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reflection

I want to create a dynamic controls generator in mvc 4, creating a controls in code using Extensions Methods like TextBoxFor(), but can pass in diamond syntax the type of my property for create a Expression.
This is my function what create a Expression.

```
 private static Expression<Func<IViewModel, TProperty>> createExpression<TProperty>(string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(myModel.GetType(), "item");
        Expression<Func<IViewModel, TProperty>> lambda;

        lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IViewModel, TProperty>>(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName), parameter);

        return lambda;
    }
```

And my call

```
InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(myhelper,createExpression<property.PropertyType>(property.Name);
```

in diamond syntax I have an error, just I want to pass a type of my property.

Comment: This is called generics.  You can't do that; you need to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Any type reference in a generic class needs to be defined at compile time.

But in your example the second type `TProperty` is not defined, but can hold any type depending on the value of `property.PropertyType`